# Limiting user input on textbox to specific Letters

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have two textboxes in which I want to limit the user, so he can only use **Y** or **N** in that textbox. How can i achieve

```css
.yes_or_no{
  font-size:xx-large;
  font-weight:900;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<input id="t1" class="yes_or_no" type="text" class="typing1"  name="txt1"   oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase(),  this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')"  maxlength="1" />
<input id="t2"class="yes_or_no" type="text" class="typing2"  name="txt2"   oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase(),  this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')"  maxlength="1" />
```

Comment: You can use a combination of the `size` and `maxlength` attribute [example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp).

Comment: add `minlength and maxlength` to your input

Comment: i used maxlenth to restrict the limit to 1 but i want to the user to type either Y or N and no other input

Comment: So this is primarily about *which* letters should be allowed, and `maxlength` is just part of the proposed solution? If you offer only two choices, why not use radio buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there! Instead of replacing the non-numeric characters with blank, you can replace anything not `Y` or `N` with blank.

See the following demo:

```html
<input type="text" class="typing1" name="txt1" id="t1" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase().replace(/[^YN]/, '')" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" class="typing2" name="txt2" id="t2" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase().replace(/[^YN]/, '')" maxlength="1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to define a pattern to only accept Y or N. - [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern)

See if this is what you are looking for.

while not putting Y or N does not submit form.

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Question?: <input type="text" name="question" pattern="^(?:Y\b|N\b)" maxlength="1" title="Introduce Y or N">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: actually want to enter only y or n and no other input ...thanks for reply